# How to remove a folder from watches in play framework?

Tags: playframework-2.0

I have a folder name *tmp* in the root directory which contains source files.

Those files change at runtime but must be ignored by the watcher of play.

Any idea ? :-)

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

To keep things simple, you should not have such temp directory *inside* the Play app, but elsewhere in a data directory, not monitored. BTW the watch monitor is not activated in production mode, so this issue is only in dev mode.